# Default dark and light theme for Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm using the app "[Auto Dark Mode](https://github.com/AutoDarkMode/Windows-Auto-Night-Mode)" to switch my Windows 11 automatically between dark and light mode when the sun rises and sets.

Visual Studio has the ability to set its theme based on the system settings:
[image]

Problem: Visual Studios default light mode is blue and I want it to be light. Is there any chance to change the default dark and light theme?

Comment: As [this Blog article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/flexible-theming-visual-studio/) says, this is not possible for now. Vote in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Pick-custom-themes-to-coordinate-with-sy/1493853?space=8 so this can be prioritized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this Visual Studio extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NickJohn.AutoThemeSwitcherForWin10DarkMode

https://github.com/JasonWei512/Visual-Studio-Auto-Theme-Switcher-for-Win10-Dark-Mode

Note that for this extension to work properly, you may need to set your Visual Studio theme to a theme other than "Use system setting".